# Generalized Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Is there any formula for calculating the coefficients of generalized characteristic polynomial $\det(A-xB)$ similar to that of $\det(A-xI)$ based on the determinant of submatrices of $A$ and $B$?